# Solr multiple query parameter search

Tags: php, solr

Hi guys I'm currently experimenting about **Solr**, just learning the basic couple of days.

Is it possible to make a query on **solr** with multiple parameters like 
last_name and first_name and dob, i am currently integrating it to a **PHP** search for fun

[Click Here to view the screenshot to my solr admin query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdL1n.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boolean operator is `AND`, not `and`. When you have `and` in your query, it queries the default search field (which in this case is `text`) for the `and` value. That field doesn't exist in your schema, so you get the error.

Use `AND` between the terms instead.